# Error in my razor code

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm not sure how to get this corrected but I have an error in the razor code here ->, where the arrow is located. Any help would be appreciated. I know I have two '@' signs but I can't access '@isDisabled' in the option element if I don't include it. Or, I'll say that with the @symbol next to the '{' the compiler throws an error.

```
@foreach (LicenseUsage license in Model.AvailableLicenses)
{
     -> @{
            bool hasBeenAssigned = Model.UserConsumedLicenses.Any(lic => lic.ClientLicenseId == license.ClientLicenseId);
            bool isAvailable = license.LicensesAvailable == 0;
            string isDisabled = (hasBeenAssigned || isAvailable) ? "" : "disabled";
         }
         <option value="@license.ClientLicenseId" id="@license.LicenseId" @isDisabled >@license.LicenseName  - (@license.LicensesConsumed/@license.LicenseQuantity) Consumed</option>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
@foreach (LicenseUsage license in Model.AvailableLicenses)
{
    bool hasBeenAssigned = Model.UserConsumedLicenses.Any(lic => lic.ClientLicenseId == license.ClientLicenseId);
    bool isAvailable = license.LicensesAvailable == 0;
    bool isDisabled = (hasBeenAssigned || isAvailable) ? false : true;
    <option value="@license.ClientLicenseId" id="@license.LicenseId" @(isDisabled ? "disabled='disabled'" : "")>@license.LicenseName  - (@license.LicensesConsumed/@license.LicenseQuantity) Consumed</option>
}
```